# Convert this Nodejs Function to C# Function

Tags: c#, node.js, cryptography, ecdh

I have this function in NodeJS and I need some help to convert to C#, my problem is get the 'buf' from randomBytes

**NodeJS Function:**

```
function generateKeys() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const dh = crypto.createECDH('prime256v1');
    dh.generateKeys();
    crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve({
        privateKey : escape(dh.getPrivateKey('base64')),
        publicKey  : escape(dh.getPublicKey('base64')),
        authSecret : escape(buf.toString('base64')),
      });
    });
  });
}
```

**C# Code so far:**

```
private static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair GenerateKeyPairEcc()
{
    var random = new Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom();
    var oid = X962NamedCurves.GetOid("prime256v1");
    var generator = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
    var genParam = new ECKeyGenerationParameters(oid, random);
    generator.Init(genParam);
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ackp = generator.GenerateKeyPair();

    return ackp;
}
public byte[] RandomBytes()
{
    byte[] random = new byte[16];
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rng.GetBytes(random);
    return random;
}
```

Comment: Whats the issue your facing?

Comment: I don´t know how to get the 'buf' data

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public byte[] RandomBytes()
{
    byte[] random = new byte[16];
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rng.GetBytes(random);
    var bytesToHex = BytesToHex(salt);
    return bytesToHex;
}

 private static string BytesToHex(byte[] toConvert)
 {
     var s = new StringBuilder(toConvert.Length * 2);
     foreach (var b in toConvert)
     {
         s.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
     }
     return s.ToString();
 }
```